# How to disable GUI sudo prompt darkening

Tags: gnome

On the GNOME desktop, when a graphical program requires privileges, ubuntu shows a prompt like this :

[image: 1]

and the whole screen around becomes darker. Is it possible to avoid this darkening but keeping the prompt, like a normal window ?

Comment: It seems gnome extension is needed for that. Something like this extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1352/no-dark-overview/

Comment: thank you for your reply. this extension might do the job but unfortunately it's incompatible with gnome 40. perhaps I can just change the version in the metadata of the extension, since this extension is very small...